# Can a hardware be custom made for a specific operational system?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu-11.04

Today I installed on my notebook(Acer Core i5, 8GB RAM) the Ubuntu version 11.04 (before it, I had installed a Windows Seven Home Premium on it).

However, when I was using Windows, it was very fast, everything works clear and quickly, and it was not the same with Ubuntu, the install process got a half hour, boot time was worst, and applications looks like "crash" on running, I mean, it was very slowly and unconfortbable to use it). I checked if drivers were ok and was everything fine(I mean, on Windows was ok and on Ubuntu too).

I made the same thing on my old computer(Toshiba Core 2 Duo, 2GB RAM), and both, Windows and Ubuntu works fine, everything oppening and working quickly. This makes me wondering, there is some specific hardware feature from the barebone, something set on factory that makes Windows work better than Linux on my new computer?

PS: I installed Windows and Ubuntu from internet sources, it weren't OEM factory images.

Comment: Unlikely, there probably is something else going on. Monitor your system to see if anything is taking up excessive amount of resources.

Comment: I suspect whatever chipset is in that acer has no native-support in ubuntu(or linux probably)  By default, linux will fail-back to a standard ide controller with no disk-caching features for the disk controller... which in many cases is crazy-slow exactly as you describe.  Once booted into Linux... try doing a "lspci".  If you see lots of "unknown" or "generic" type devices instead of named "VIA Technologies" or "Intel Corporation" type stuff... that's a dead-give-away.  (I hate Acer anything BTW)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the computer contains hardware that requires a driver to work properly, especially a hard drive controller or something to enable specific performance features of the platform, then *yes, a specific operating system (that contains the necessary drivers) can work better on that hardware than other operating systems.*

Back about 10 years ago when processor architectures were changing and [Northbridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_%28computing%29)/[Southbridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_%28computing%29) combos were quite common we had what was known as "chipset drivers" which were actually almost mandatory to be installed on a computer as the first item after installing windows, because they enabled (now default) options like [UDMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDMA) for the hard drive controller (rather than the much slower and CPU-intensive [PIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_input/output)) which was an immediate performance boost.  The also tended to contain fixes that made the hardware behave better and fixed some bugs.

Nowadays a lot more of this kind of thing is integrated into Windows by default, with Microsoft playing more of a active role to prevent these kind of chipset drivers from being necessary.

It is quite possible that Ubuntu does not have some driver that is necessary to enable the performance features on your machine, or even may be using a "non-optimal" driver which could be slowing it down.

If the hardware manufacturer only ever envisaged running Windows on it, then it may be that it has a piece of hardware that Windows knows how to deal with but a driver has not been written for in Linux yet.

Answer (score 2):

Often the open-source Linux hardware drivers are much worse than the proprietary and Windows ones. You may need to enable additional software sources in Ubuntu and install some proprietary ones, especially for your video card.

Ubuntu's Unity is also well-know for its sluggishness and resource-hogging abilities. If you use an alternative desktop environment with the more optimized drivers, you should find Linux to be snappier than Window on the same hardware.

As to your original question: in a traditional sense, the only way that a hardware can be said to be made for a specific system is when it use a different architecture. Any other incompatibilities can be solved at the software level.